# HTML/JS: Validating value in <selected>-list

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm really new to this and working on a JavaScript code and I want to see if a dropdownlist has any choosen value. How do i do that?

I tried:

```
var selectObj = form.document.getElementById('myListId');
var selectInd = selectObj.selectedInd;
```

and tried:

```
if(selectInd == "")
```

to check if it was empty.

What do I need to change to make it work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A drop-down, by design, always has a value selected. If you just want to leave an empty value first to not choose something for the user, you can simply check if it's value is empty.

```
document.getElementById("validate").onclick = function() {
    if (document.getElementById("foo").value == "")
        alert("invalid");
    else
        alert("valid");
};
```

[**Live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/vA8hn/)

According to comments, this might not work in older versions of IE. Be sure to test it there if you need to support those browsers.

Comment: @Galled, might you please be more specific so I can edit my answer appropriately please?

Comment: when I try your live example in IE7 always give me `invalid`.

Comment: @Galled ah, well JSFiddle doesn't work atll for me in IE, so I'll just add a warning. Thanks.

Comment: yeah, in IE 7 onclick does not take a function, it takes a string, where as firefox and chrome accept functions for those attributes.  I suggest using JQuery or YUI to attach such events.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<select id="myListId">
  <option value="">- Select an option-</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Javascript

```
function checkvalue(){
    var selectObj = form.document.getElementById('myListId');
    if (selectObj.value != "") {/* DO something */}
}
```

Now you can execute this function on change of the select box, or when you submit the form, it is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to read this [example](http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/tutorial002.html).

You are trying compare a number (`selectObj.selectedIndex`) with a string (`""`), you should write something like this:

```
var selectObj = document.getElementById('myListId'),
    selectInd = selectObj.selectedIndex,
    selectedVal = selectObj.options[selectInd].value;

if(selectedVal== "") {
    /* do your stuff*/
}
```

Only to notice: This only would work (detect a value equal to `""`) with an html like this:

```
<select id="myListId">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Empty value</option>
    <option value="1">Non empty value</option>
</select>
```

Or when the user has been selected the option "Empty value".

**EDIT:**
Try with this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vA8hn/12/). This demo also works in IE7.